# How do I add margin to a JavaFX element using CSS?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, javafx-css

I have the following fragment of FXML:

```xml
<VBox fx:id="paneLeft">
    <TextField promptText="Password"/>
    <Button fx:id="btnLogin" text="Login" maxWidth="10000"/>
    <Hyperlink text="Registration"/>
</VBox>
```

Is it possible to add a spacing of 10px between the `Button` and `Hyperlink` elements using CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [-fx-spacing](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#vbox) to first VBox in Uluk's solution, not perfect, but at least you can specify the space amount via css rather than in fxml.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems you cannot. JavaFX has a limited support on CSS right now.

> However, the CSS padding and margins properties are supported on some
>   JavaFX scene graph objects.

says the official CSS Reference Guide. So workaround could be to use extra other layout, another VBox for instance:

```
<VBox fx:id="paneLeft" spacing="10">
    <VBox fx:id="innerPaneLeft">
        <TextField promptText="Password"/>
        <Button fx:id="btnLogin" text="Login" maxWidth="10000"/>
    </VBox>
    <Hyperlink text="Registration"/>
</VBox>
```

---

**Update:**
Found a bit more perfect way of doing it, but still not by CSS.

```
 <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

 <VBox fx:id="paneLeft">
        <TextField promptText="Password"/>
        <Button fx:id="btnLogin" text="Login" maxWidth="10000">
            <VBox.margin>
                <Insets>
                    <bottom>10</bottom>
                </Insets>
            </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <Hyperlink text="Registration"/>
 </VBox>
```

This avoids defining an unnecessary extra layout.

Answer (score 78):

Probably really late to the party, but I use another approach which might be helpful for others too.

There's no `-fx-margin: 5px;` CSS property for JavaFX buttons, but you can workaround the behaviour with a combination of `-fx-padding`, `-fx-border-insets` and `-fx-background-inset`s.

For example a button with a 5px  margin.

```css
.button-with-margin {
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-border-insets: 5px;
    -fx-background-insets: 5px;
}
```

Alternatively you can also define a higher padding and lower insets values in case you want a padding and a margin.

Comment: exactly what I needed, its never to late. Thanks alot!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42466235/873282 for a documentation of the `insets` properties