# JavaFX: How to define margin to TextField in css?

Tags: css, javafx

Is it possible to define padding and margin for `TextField`s in JavaFX using CSS? I have tried `-fx-padding` and some other properties, but no effect.  I am using JavaFX 2.2 which is included in the latest version of Java 7.

I have many textfields and doing something like:

```
    <GridPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="60.0" right="0.0" top="10.0"/>
    </GridPane.margin>
```

after each textfield is not a good solution for me.

Answer (score 7):

Modified copy from [Confgure margin for individual element via java fx css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977100/confgure-margin-for-individual-element-via-java-fx-css/33141605#33141605)

Theres no -fx-margin:5px css property for javafx textfields, but you can workaround the behaviour with a combination of padding, border-insets and background-insets.

For example a text-field with a 5px margin.

```
.text-field-with-margin {
    -fx-padding: 5px;
    -fx-border-insets: 5px;
    -fx-background-insets: 5px;
}
```

Alternatively you can also define a higher padding and lower insets values in case you want a padding and a margin.

Answer (score 0):

`TextField`s in JavaFX have the CSS class `text-field`.

You can define the following rule:

```
.text-field {
   ....
}
```

But I think that you want to create some spacing around the fields, right? Sadly, there is no margin property for `TextField`s.

I usually define a padding for the wrapping `Control`. In this case you would define a padding for all GridPanes.

For more information please have a look at the [JavaFX CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Answer (score 0):

Preferred to use CSS to much more easier design a gui in your javafx.

```
#idTextField{
  -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
}
```