# How to align vertically children of StatusBar in FXControls?

Tags: java, javafx, vertical-alignment, controlsfx

I have created [`StatusBar`](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/StatusBar.html) in the following way:

```
    <StatusBar>
        <rightItems>
            <Label>Memory used: </Label>
            <TextField editable="false" fx:id="memoryUsedField"></TextField>
            <Label>MB</Label>
        </rightItems>
    </StatusBar>
```

and it looks like this actually:

[image]

I.e. `Label` is centered other way that `TextField` vertically.

How to fix?

Comment: did you try to use css? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530694/javafx-how-to-define-margin-to-textfield-in-css

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but the status bar's `leftItems` and `rightItems` are [implemented as `HBox`s](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/3891949f0eb1b1413fe03516233ef4a12f7b4e42/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/StatusBarSkin.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), so you can use [`HBox` style properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#hbox) for them. So try the following in an external style sheet:

```
.status-bar .right-items {
    -fx-alignment: center-right ;
}
```

( `baseline-right` might actually look better).