# -fx-background-radius and -fx-background-insets in JavaFX

Tags: css, button, javafx-8

I am working with JavaFX and I want to customize a button. I saw several characteristics that can be styled. Among them I found two that are unknown to me.

```css
.button {
    -fx-padding: 5 22 5 22;   
    -fx-border-color: #121212;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #555555;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 11pt;
    -fx-text-fill: #d8d8d8;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

what are these two properties:

```css
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
```

and

```css
 -fx-background-radius: 0;
```

I saw [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html), but it is very vague for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These 2 properties are documented in the linked document, but I'd prefer using the latest version: [JavaFX CSS Reference: *Region*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)

Those 2 properties are used to create the [`background`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) of the `Button`; they are used as the constuctor parameters for the [`BackgroundFill` constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BackgroundFill.html#BackgroundFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii-javafx.geometry.Insets-) (4 `BackgroundFill`s will be used for the background since `0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2` contains 4 sets of insets).

#### `-fx-background-insets`

This specifies the distance from the `Button`'s bounds where the background should be drawn. E.g. if you have a button positioned at `x=50, y=150, width=200, height=100` and use insets `10 20 30 40` the region used for the background is `x=50+40=90, y=150+10=160, width=200-20-40=140, height=100-10-30=60`.

#### `-fx-background-radius`

The background is drawn as a rounded rectangle. This is the radius of the corners. In this case `0` means the background will be drawn as a non-rounded rectangle.

Comment: I got your points. Now I know inset meaning. However, what are those 3 comma separated numbers after four zero , I mean `0, 1, 2 `

Comment: @Alireza You've got 4 insets (; you could e.g. also write `-fx-background-color: red, blue, green, yellow;` to specify different background colors for the different fills).  You can specify different values for all sides of the insets or you can use the shortened version, if all 4 values are the same `2` has the same meaning as `2 2 2 2`.