# JavaFX - Set Margin Between TitledPane

Tags: java, css, javafx

Is there a way to set margin between TitledPane in javafx?

I created multiple titledpanes and put them altogether inside a `VBox`. I want it to have a gap between each titledpane.

I looked up `setMargin()` method to achieve it, but it doesn't seem to be exist.

I also tried with css but it is not working at all.

**CSS**

```
.titled-pane {   
    -fx-font-weifght: bold;
    -fx-margin: 5;
}

.titled-pane .title {
    -fx-background-color: #990000; 
    -fx-padding:2 3 3 10;
    -fx-margin: 5;
}
```

Comment: If you put them in an HBox, could you then set the gap between them?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33141605/3992939

Comment: What margin are you asking about? It sounds like you added multiple `TitledPane`s to some parent... Without details about this the question will probably be unanswerable.

Comment: @fabian, you're correct. I created multiple titledpanes and want to put gap between each other.

Comment: VBox.setMargin(child, value) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very basic. When instantiating `VBox`, declare the spacing too. Example:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
```

The codes above will give `5` pixels gap between children.